# Android Share Link with WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am trying to share link with my android app with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share);
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

this is the `share` Strong :

```
Check out my link:\n http://my123domain.com/v.php?vid=123456-123456-123456
```

But when i share it with `Whats App` the link is not click able,
Any idea Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatsapp does not allow sending clickable text links to people who do not have you in their contact list. Make sure receiving party have you in their contact list.

Comment: Hi @mk_ is it still applicable today or have things changed?