# Link in WhatsApp not clickable

Tags: hyperlink, whatsapp

I have a problem, when I share my play store app link on WhatsApp to some unknown user then he cant click on link (mean link is grey not openable).

Link become clickable once user trust me and add me to his/her contacts.

Is this feature is of WhatsApp for security issues or am I doing something wrong?

I read in some blog that WhatsApp not allow links to be clickable from some random users until you trust him.

I just want to confirm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364392/891194